# Angular 2 building a Configuration Service

Tags: angular

In my deployment process we have different environments - dev and prod. Therefore we have e.G. different Api Urls and other stuff which should be configurable. As I am using Angular 2 CLI there are environment files.

To have access to the configuration files my first idea was to build a service which gets the environment files and reads the properties. The service is then provided so any component can access it.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class UtilService {

   constructor() { }

}
```

Is there a better approach than using a service? I don´t want to import the environment files in every component.